# Why can't I sample a texture in a vertex shader?

Tags: unity, shaders, cg, shaderlab

I'm old in Game Development but very new in shader writing. I just want a shader that transform from 1 texture to another. So I did start learning shader writing and wrote my desired shader. But during writing one thing I cannot understand as I am very dumb in shader writing that if I assign `fixed4` color with `COLOR` semantic in `vertex` method then compiler gives the following error.

> Shader error in 'Hamza/TwoTextures': cannot map expression to vs_4_0 instruction set at line 39 (on glcore)
>
> Compiling Vertex program
>   Platform defines: UNITY_ENABLE_REFLECTION_BUFFERS UNITY_PBS_USE_BRDF1 UNITY_SPECCUBE_BOX_PROJECTION UNITY_SPECCUBE_BLENDING SHADER_API_DESKTOP UNITY_TEXTURE_ALPHASPLIT_ALLOWED

Here is the not working shader code,

```
Shader "Hamza/TwoTextures"{
    Properties{
        [NoScaleOffset]
        _Texture1 ("Texture 1",2D) = "white"{}

        [NoScaleOffset]
        _Texture2 ("Texture 2",2D) = "white"{}

        _Mixer ("Mixer", Range(0,1)) = 0
    }

    SubShader{
        Pass{
            CGPROGRAM

            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            sampler2D   _Texture1;
            sampler2D   _Texture2;
            float       _Mixer;

            struct appdata{
                fixed4 vertex   : POSITION;
                fixed2 tex      : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f{
                fixed4 pos      : SV_POSITION;
                fixed2 tex      : TEXCOORD0;
                fixed4 col      : COLOR;
            };

            v2f vert(appdata i){

                v2f o;
                o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP,i.vertex);
                o.tex = i.tex;

                // Giving error on this line
                o.col = (tex2D(_Texture1,i.tex) * _Mixer) + (tex2D(_Texture2,i.tex) * (1 - _Mixer));
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag(v2f v) : COLOR
            {
                return v.col;
            }

            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

And if I write same expression to throw it as return `fixed4` value in `fragment` method then everything is working fine.

Here is working shader code,

```
Shader "Hamza/TwoTextures"{
    Properties{
        [NoScaleOffset]
        _Texture1 ("Texture 1",2D) = "white"{}

        [NoScaleOffset]
        _Texture2 ("Texture 2",2D) = "white"{}

        _Mixer ("Mixer", Range(0,1)) = 0
    }

    SubShader{
        Pass{
            CGPROGRAM

            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            sampler2D   _Texture1;
            sampler2D   _Texture2;
            float       _Mixer;

            struct appdata{
                fixed4 vertex   : POSITION;
                fixed2 tex      : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f{
                fixed4 pos      : SV_POSITION;
                fixed2 tex      : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            v2f vert(appdata i){

                v2f o;
                o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP,i.vertex);
                o.tex = i.tex;
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR
            {
                // It is giving me no error
                return (tex2D(_Texture1,i.tex) * _Mixer) + (tex2D(_Texture2,i.tex) * (1 - _Mixer));
            }

            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

**Can anyone explain me that why it is happening? And what is the difference between them?**

As I mentioned that I did start learning only two days before. I'm sort of noob in this.

Comment: Here's effectively the same question in a different shader dialect: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16063/why-cant-i-add-a-float4-read-from-a-texture2d-sample-in-the-vertex-shader

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error here is that you're trying to sample from a texture in a vertex shader the way you would in a fragment or pixel shader.

Vertex texture fetches are a little bit special. They're only supported in [Shader Model 3 and up](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-ShaderCompileTargets.html), and they're unable to use the `tex2d()` function.

That may sound odd, but `tex2D()` is really a shortcut that says "figure out the right [mip level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap) to sample automatically" - in a fragment shader this is done using implicit derivatives, but those aren't available at the vertex stage.

So, we need to use the more explicit `tex2dlod()` form (which works at both the vertex and fragment stages). This takes a 4-component vector, whose `x` and `y` are the familiar texture coordinates in uv space, and `w` indicates which mip level to sample from (0 being the highest resolution available).

Comment: This mean second one is optimised and right way? right?

Comment: @HamzaHasan Which one are you asking about? Your second shader example with the texture fetch in the fragment shader? Or the option of using `tex2dlod` in the vertex shader? It all depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: My second shader example, what about the current case? Means about to transform textures, what I'm doing in it

Comment: @HamzaHasan It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. If your second shader is accomplishing what you need though, then it sounds like you're on a good track.

Comment: I'm trying to change textures from a `Range` value. If range is 0 then only 1st texture will be visible on mesh, if range is 1 then only second texture will be visible and if range is 0.5 then both textures (blended, if I'm not wrong) will show up on mesh. Well Thank You so much for your response. I was just curious about that issue. Thanks again.

Comment: zw are both mip levels, if anisotropy is off then it probably uses w

Comment: @Khlorghaal that does not match [the NVIDIA documentation for tex2Dlod](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/cg/tex2Dlod.html) which specifies that the w component is used for level of detail. If you want to use anisotropy then you want `tex2Dgrad`, also available in CG as an overload of `tex2D` where you pass two computed partial derivative vectors as the 3rd & 4th parameters.