# (URP Shader Graph) Why can´t I connect a float into another float 'slot'? Are there different types of floats?

Tags: unity, unity-shader-graph

[image]

So, here I´m just trying to take in a `Vector3` (resulting from multiplying some noise and a sample texture) and putting it as the vertex position, but for some reason that´s not working.

Even when I decompose the `Vector3` into `float`s, I somehow can´t connect a `float` into another `float`, as you see below.

[image]

Now, is this a bug or am I missing something really important? And if so, I´d be thankful if you could point me in the right direction, as I really have no clue what´s happening at the moment. I'm obviously a newcomer.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem and noticed that it occurs as soon as you try to add a SampleTexture2D node to a graph that feeds into the Vertex output node.

Comment: Could be `SampleTexture2D` is using `tex2d`/ `sample` under the hood, [which is not valid at the vertex stage](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/114856/39518). If you can force it to use `tex2dlod` or the DX11+ equivalent, that might solve it.

Comment: Loool, @Philipp thanks for the work
I unplugged all Vertex connections, connected my floats at the other end of the graph
and replugged the Vertex connections, seems to be a valid workaround for now
currently in 2022.3.7f1 - HDRP 14.0.8